# Text-Overflow Ellipsis for Inline List

Tags: html, css, list

On my page, I need to display an inline list of values, separated by a comma. If the list goes past its boundary and overflows, I need to end the text with ellipsis.

I originally did this in a `<p>` tag, like so:

```
<p style="border: 1px solid black; width: 300px; padding: 5px; white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis">
    <span>testing, </span>
    <span>testing, </span>
    <span>testing, </span>
    <span>testing, </span>
    <span>testing, </span>
    <span>testing, </span>
    <span>testing, </span>
    <span>testing, </span>
</p>
```

This looks like this: 
[image]

However, now I need to achieve the same display, but by using list semantics (`<ul>` and `<li>`). I'm being asked to do this to provide extra screen reader support.

I cannot figure out how to achieve that type of overflow styling in a list.
I've found posts on how to end the `<li>` in ellipsis, but that's not what I want.

Any tips?

I whipped up a stackblitz with my examples here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/html-basics-6kc6im?file=index.html

And a note, while the stackbitz is a simple HTML app, I'm actually doing this in an Angular project (v10).

Comment: `<ul>` and `<li>` are by default block-level-elements. Simply change the `<li>` to be an inline element (`display: inline`).

Comment: user wants an ellipses after X length, not on every single li element, li elements also need to be inline.

Comment: Thank you, but if I add `style="display: inline"` to my '<li>` elements, it still doesn't do the ellipsis overflow, so that solution doesn't work for me. (You can check stackblitz for the example I added with your suggestion.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<p style="border: 1px solid black; width: 300px; padding: 5px; white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis">
    <span>testing, </span>
    <span>testing, </span>
    <span>testing, </span>
    <span>testing, </span>
    <span>testing, </span>
    <span>testing, </span>
    <span>testing, </span>
    <span>testing, </span>
</p>

<ul style="border: 1px solid black; width: 300px; padding: 5px; white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis">
    <li>testing, </li>
    <li>testing, </li>
    <li>testing, </li>
    <li>testing, </li>
    <li>testing, </li>
    <li>testing, </li>
    <li>testing, </li>
    <li>testing, </li>
</ul>

</body>

</html>
```

try:

```
ul {
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Yeah! Thank you. This is just what I needed. I updated the stackblitz with the fix for those who need the answer in the future.